# Получение выделенного текста из textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Всем доброго вечера, у меня стала в задаче такая проблема как получения выделенного текста только из textarea, долго колупался в гугле но так дельного ничего и не нашёл, какие-то проверки на браузер, и работает такое выделение не только для textarea она захватывает весь документ. Можно ли это как нибудь реализовать на jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендовал бы вот такой плагин с хорошей браузерной поддержкой.

http://dwieeb.github.io/jquery-textrange/

Answer (score 2):

Немного гугла и [английского SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275761/how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox-control-with-javascript)

```
function ShowSelection()
{
  var textComponent = document.getElementById('Editor');
  var selectedText;
  // IE version
  if (document.selection != undefined)
  {
    textComponent.focus();
    var sel = document.selection.createRange();
    selectedText = sel.text;
  }
  // Mozilla version
  else if (textComponent.selectionStart != undefined)
  {
    var startPos = textComponent.selectionStart;
    var endPos = textComponent.selectionEnd;
    selectedText = textComponent.value.substring(startPos, endPos)
  }
  alert("You selected: " + selectedText);
}
```